# cannot access array defined in external file, W/O the keyword "extern"

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I discover that no matter how, I cannot access an array defined in an external file. So I do some simple test like these in both c and c++:

In C:

main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int func();
char arr[100]="";

int main()
{
  for(int i=0;i<=9;++i){
    func();
    printf("%s\n",arr);
  }
return 0;
}
```

func.c

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

extern char* arr;
int func(){
  strcat(arr,"hello");          // try to access arr here
  return 0;
}
```

In C++:

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int func();
char arr[100]="";

int main()
{
  for(int i=0;i<=10;++i){
    func();
    cout<<arr<<endl;
  }
return 0;
}
```

func.cpp

```
#include<cstring>
extern char* arr;

int func(){
  strcat(arr,"hello");      // try to access arr here

  return 0;
}
```

Pretty simple test as you can see. No matter what method I use to access an array in an external file, I got segmentation fault.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe it is because in main you declared it as arr[100] and in func you declare it as *arr

Comment: Yes, it is. Those are obviously two different types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable linking isn't type-safe.

The problem is that you're *defining* the name "arr" to refer to an array.
Assuming that the array is located at address 0x10, it looks something like this:

```
Address     0x10  0x11  0x12  0x13
Content    |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0 | (... 100 zeroes in total)
```

The name "arr" refers to the location where this array is stored.

In "func.cpp" (and "func.c" - they work exactly the same) you claim, or *declare*, that the name "arr" refers to a pointer.
This is a lie because it is not what you defined it to be, but the compiler and the linker blindly trust you.

This lie causes the code in `func` to interpret the value stored at the address 0x10 as a pointer instead of an array.
With 32-bit pointers, that would be

```
Address  0x10   0x14
Content |  0  |  0  | (...)
```

And when you `strcat` onto `0`, things don't go well.

If you store something more distinct than zeroes in the array (e.g. `"\1\2\3\4"`) and examine the pointer in a debugger, it will be more obvious that the array's elements have "become" the pointer's value.

The fix is to make the proper claim; that `arr` is an array:

```
extern char arr[];
```

(Note that in variable declarations, as opposed to function parameters, `char arr[]` is *not* the same as `char* arr`.)

Comment: @walkerlala No, it's just lying about the type of "arr". Both "arr"s refer to the same place, but under different interpretations of what is stored in that place.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
extern char arr[];
```

instead of

```
extern char* arr;
```

Though an array is implicitly converted into a pointer in many situations in C, an array is not same as a pointer. What you have is a pointer, not declaration. The declaration in func.c doesn't match defintion in main.c.

Comment: So you mean that instead of makeing the "arr " accessible, I declare a pointer (of type char)?

Comment: @walkerlala The problem isn't that it's not accessible, it's that you claim that it's a pointer when it's actually an array.

Comment: According to my understanding, that causes problem because instead of "extern" the var, I declare a new pointer. Is that right?

Comment: @BlueMoon The "pointer" is the first `sizeof(char*)` elements of the array, reinterpreted.

Comment: To put in other words: `arr` in `char arr[]="abcd";` refers to the base address of the array (which is the location of char `'a'`) whereas `arr` in `char *arr="abcd";` simply *points to* the base address. molbdnilo's answer explained it better.

Answer (score -1):

simple thing is you have to use extern keyword at both the places.

in main.c

```
extern char arr[100]="";
```

and in func.c

```
extern char *arr;
```

this will tell compiler that arr is an extern variable name, so that it can be accessed in other files.